# android service and "alert window"

Tags: java, android, service

I wish to use service in background of my application. When some special place is reached inside service I wish to stop it and display to user notification, which wont disapear until he or she clicks "OK" (some kind of alert window). When he or she clicks "OK" -> I wish some data reached in service be passed to my Activity.

Can I please for help. I have my service already running well, I wish to use Alert Dialog - but have no idea how to invoke it from service.

Comment: Take a lock at [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) for showing the info. `Activity.sendBroadcast()` for sending the information from the service and [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for receiving it in the Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [official documentation states](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html), *A background service should never launch an activity on its own in order to receive user interaction*.
Instead you should fire a notification to the notification bar. The notification can be flagged insistent and vibrate until the user takes action, which is as strong as not dismissing a popup until the user clicks a button. Follow the link above for good (and official) tutorial on notifications

If you really want to launch an activity (and pop up a dialog) you must set the following flag to your intent first otherwise you'll get an exception.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once a certain point in your service is reached start an activity and dont use setContent view, but just use this in onCreate() to show a alert dialog.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("ALERT")
   .setCancelable(false)
   .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            MyActivity.this.finish();
       }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
       }
   });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

When the user presses okay, the dialog will close with the activity.

EDIT:

For the data you want to send to the activity just put it in the bundle starting the Activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();

// see Bundle.putInt, etc.
// Bundle.putSerializable for full Objects (careful there)

 b.putXXXXX("key", ITEM);  
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);

// -- later, in Activity
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
int i = b.getInt("key");
```

Comment: Or you can call dialog.cancle() in  ok button, but i would suggest closing out the whole activity.

Comment: but the activity is running, service is running in background, I wish to somehow "update" activity - > change status radiobutton to "checked" dependently on service result